# OnClickListener() on last Spinner's element

Tags: java, android

Hi i have Spinner(SpinnerP) from ArrayList (worklist) . Last element in worklist is "add"

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinneritem, worklist);
         dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner);
         SpinnerP.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Spinner work fine but i need to create something like onClickListener for last element in Spinner. It'll be action ADD to Spinner. How can i do that ?

When I use Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(), i have 2x errors

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - OnItemSelectedListener cannot be resolved to a type
    - The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> is not applicable for the 
     arguments (new OnItemSelectedListener(){})
```

Comment: You need to import the `onItemSelectedListener` like this: `import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;` where all of your other imports are. Also, post your new code.

Comment: Post the new code you are using.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean finding the `spinner` from your view? Just post your code? And what's with the comment deleting?

Comment: I paste your code in wrong place, so window with import suggestion not apear, now your code works perfect :) Sorry for confusion and thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `onItemSelectedListener`, then check if it is that item. For example:

```
Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

                String selectedValue = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

                if(selectedValue.equals("add")){
                          // add item to spinner
                }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

You need to import `onItemSelectedListener` like this:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        **// Here you check, it is last item or not then take action.**
    if((worklist.size()-1)==position)
    {
    }
                    }

```
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    // your code here
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does work but I think it is not clean to check if the String value of the selected item is the String of the last item.
`AdapterView` provides the method `getCount()` which returns the total number of items. Now you can check if the position(+1 of course) of the selected item matches the total count:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(parent.getCount() == position + 1) {// last item
                // your code here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```